# MongoDB not updated when i create new Scema model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoDb 7.0.0. when i create new Schema in my model folder then i can not show new schema in mongodb.
[image]

at first i create user, profile, courses, categories, otps schema then i can show my schema in mongodb but when i create new schema "Section" and "Subsection" then i can show only "Section" schema "Subsection" is not display.

**here is my Section schema**

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const SectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sectionName: {
    type: String,
  },

  sectionDescription: {
    type: String,
  },

  subsection: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Subsection"
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Section", SectionSchema);
```

**here is my Subsection schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const SubsectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  SubsectionName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  SubsectionDescription: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  video: {
    type: String,
  },
  
  timeDuration: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Subsection", SubsectionSchema);
```

I can not find where is the problem. Please help me